# Globals, inheritance and scope

Tags: oop, inheritance, global

What is the best way to pass high level data, like the grid data of a map, to something really low level like a single unit or character?

I guess I could pass it to the unit manager and then to the unit or store it somewhere globally, but both ways seem dirty and horrible.

What is considered best practice?

Comment: why would you be passing grid data to something like a character?

Comment: There is a graphical representation of where the character can move and it needs to evaluate the current map to know what to draw.

Comment: Oh sorry I was confused by what you meant by low level, I thought you meant like an ASCII character or something :-P I would have a ValidMove object that works out if a move is valid by querying the map for each step. For example, the character says to the ValidMove object "Can I move here?" with some desired destination and the ValidMove object works out the steps of the move and then queries the map for each step. The map might say for each step "flat" "flat" "flat" "mountain", and the ValidMove object then says to the character "Nope, sorry mountain in way".

Comment: How would I pass the map down to the ValidMove object? Pass it from the Main object?

Comment: Yeah, pass a reference to the map object to the constructor of ValidMove. ValidMove object can then ask the map when ever it needs to to check a grid coord. Pass the ValidMove object to the character at construction. You could have a different ValidMove object depending on the move rules for character type. Similar to how in the real world you use GPS on your phone. You don't ask the Earth where are you and the Earth doesn't care how to get to your house. The GPS knows where it is from the Earth and it knows where you want to go from you telling it. Your GPS sits between you and the Earth.